# How to see the files present in changelist using command line

Tags: svn

I created one changelist. I moved 2 files to it. If i give svn status command, it will show the change list and the files present in it. after doing the commit. If i try to give the svn status. I am not see the changelist and the files present in it. is it not possible to see the changelist and files present in it after committing to the repositary?. Is there any command to see the change list created by ourself apart from svn status command?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for:

```
svn diff --summarize -r0:100
```

You may also want to take a look at:

```
svn log
```

depending on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding your question:  perhaps what you are experiencing is the fact that, by default, when you `svn commit`, changelist assignments are removed from the files.  If you want to `svn commit` and preserve your changelist, you have to use the `--keep-changelists` switch.  Example:  (where changelist is called "test")

```
svn commit --changelist test --keep-changelists
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. is there any other way to see the files present in changelist apart from svn status command.because if i give svn status command, it will show other changes also. But i want to see only the list of changelist and files present in it.